# linux find with exec with > not working when inside cron

Tags: bash, cron

I created a simple bash script to: find some files and execute a command.
This command must output a content that i need to store for each execution.

So, i have something like:

```
find /some/folder/ -name "*txt" -exec /bin/sh -c "/path/command -x -f {} > {}.pdf" \;
```

So, i will find txt files inside **/some/folder/** and foreach one i will execute **/path/command** and pass filepath to parameter **-f** of **/path/command** and will get binary, so i just need to get ouput and add a suffix **.pdf**.

The problem is that, when i execute this by hand, everything went fine.
But when i put this inside a cron, this happens:

- if exists **/some/folder/sample.txt** i got a **/some/folder/sample.txt.pdf** (so, **find** and **>** seems to work ok) but seems to be executed by **/path/command** but without **-f /some/folder/sample.txt** parameter.
- **/path/command** seems to not get **-f /some/folder/sample.txt** and outputs a warning message inside created **/some/folder/sample.txt.pdf** indicating that need to get a **-f** parameter with something.

Note that, again, if i execute this by command line (and not by cron), everything went fine.

Is there anything wrong i'm doing here?

thanks for support.

Comment: You could try replacing `/path/command` with `echo`, so that the .pdf file contains the full command it is trying to execute.  This might help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: In the `cron` case, what does the `pdf` have in it? I'm wondering if the double quotes on the `sh` command are being honored in that case.

Comment: The same problem, even easier case - find /var/tmp/sth -iname *.pdf works in shell, doesn't work in cron. /usr/bin/find changes nothing

Answer (score -1):

You should use absolute pthes.

'/usr/bin/find'  instaed of 'find'

To see what's wrong, invoke your command line this way

```
env -i  mycommands ....
```

This will strip off the environment of your session and run the commands in an environment which is very like the cron environment.

Then correct your entry in the crontab.